# Scrapy - extract nested 'img src' using xPathSelector

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am relatively new to using Scrapy or python for that matter. I am looking to extract the  from a few different links and I am having issues using a HTMLXPathSelector expression (syntax). I have looked at extensive documentation for the proper syntax but have yet to figure out a solution.

**Here is an example of a link I am trying to extract the 'img src' from:**

[Page I am trying to extract the img src url from](http://www.geek.com/articles/gadgets/kindle-fire-hd-8-9-on-sale-for-50-off-today-only-20121210/)

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class GeekSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "geekS"
    allowed_domains = ["geek.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.geek.com/articles/gadgets/kindle-fire-hd-8-9-on-sale-for-50-off-today-only-20121210/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        imgurl = hxs.select("//div[@class='article']//a/img/@src").extract()
        return imgurl
```

I think I have figured out the syntax for the x.select statement but, since I am new to this syntax/method I am not sure.

Here is my items.py file, basically followed the scrapy tutorial for this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class GeekItem(Item):
    imgsrc = Field()
```

**To clarify:** What I am looking to do is extract the img src url that is on the page. I dont need to extract all image src's which I have already figured out(much easier).

I am just looking to narrow it down and only extract that particular url of the img src. *(I will be using this across multiple pages on this site)*

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

**EDIT - Updated Code** I was getting some syntax errors with geek = geek() So I changed it slightly to hopefully be easier to understand and function

Comment: So you only want the image that is a clickable link (ie "kindle-fire-hd.jpg")?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I dont even want to return the image itself, just the url for the image so I can store it.

Comment: To avoid confusion, please update the first spider code that was posted and delete the second one. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, wasn't sure if it was more confusing to remove the old code or leave it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your xpath expression should be more like this. I tested it on another page ([the Amazon shipping center article](http://www.geek.com/articles/gadgets/inside-amazons-ridiculously-huge-phoenix-arizona-shipping-center-20121130/)) and it returned all ten of the clickable images.

```
geek['imgsrc'] = x.select("//div[@class='article']//a/img/@src").extract()
```

To fix your other issue, you need to import GeekItem into your GeekSpider code.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from geekspider.items import GeekItem # I'm guessing the name of your project here

class GeekSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "geekS"
    allowed_domains = ["geek.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.geek.com/articles/gadgets/kindle-fire-hd-8-9-on-sale-for-50-off-today-only-20121210/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = GeekItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item['imgsrc'] = hxs.select("//div[@class='article']//a/img/@src").extract()
        return item
```

Comment: Thanks! Since asking the question I have changed the spider up slightly due to some syntax errors. I attached the updated code above. I am no longer receiving the errors but when checking scraped_data.json all that is returned is a [ symbol. Any ideas?

Comment: I also attached my items.py file, I didn't think anything is wrong with it (as i followed the scrapy tutorial almost exact) but just to save possible time and confusion, I attached it above. I did notice I am receiving an error that says "spider must return Request, BaseItem or None." Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, cleared up the confusion and the problems I was having. Now I just need to get this to work across multiple urls pulled from my db and pipeline it back into my db. Should be fun. Thanks again!